# Обособление «кто-нибудь»

Tags: запятые, местоимения, обращение

Можете сказать, обращение ли это, и его надо обособлять?

`Можете(,) кто-нибудь(,) взять-таки чёрно-гелевую ручку, т. к., очевидно, у меня её нет-с.`

Comment: *может кто-нибудь...

Comment: @Буратино Здесь в авторском варианте произношение вставочное, выделяется голосом как обращение.

Comment: @Sharon Тогда причем тут "кто-нибудь" можно вставить опять же любое слово. Можете, Лопата, помочь? И при обращениях говорят: можете, кто-то. Кто-нибудь - это не обращение, это наречие какое-то. Хотя в словарях пишут, что это местоимение, но я бы не ставил его в один ряд с местоимениями. Потому что, кто-нибудь употребляется в отрицаниях или запретах. А отождествлять его с "любой" неверное. Вот смотрите: "Узнав о сем, новогородцы немедленно выгнали псковских купцов, объявив, что если кто-нибудь из них приедет к ним, то будет сожжен с своим имением" Карамзин.

Comment: Разве тут кто-нибудь - любой? нет, не любой, а запрет именно для определенных людей, кто-то кто будет из них или подобный им, а не любой другой. Причем тут нибудь - очень своеобразно, так как отрицает кто,  то есть вы или другие вы, не вы конкретно, но как вы.

Comment: Поэтому кто-нибудь есть смысл выделать, но обращение это по сути, ни к одному из тех, кого я вижу или кому говорю, а другие. То есть звучит вроде: Вы мне помогите, и другие, если слышите, тоже.

Comment: @Буратино Вы всё верно говорить, но не договариваете: вывода нет. Нужно коротко ответить на конкретные вопросы.  Обособляем или нет? Это обращение или нет? Почему обособляем или не обособляем? КТО-НИБУДЬ, кого-нибудь, кому-нибудь, кого-нибудь, кем-нибудь, о ком-нибудь; местоим. сущ. Какой-л. человек, безразлично кто. Позовите кого-нибудь сюда! Хочется о ком-нибудь заботиться.

Comment: @Sharon кто-нибудь говорят в растерянности, это как междометие или наречие восклицание, обособляем как междометие. Но в данной фразе оно не уместно. Кто-нибудь уместно в отрицательных: не берите черные ручки, и, кто-нибудь, скажите Леопольду, чтобы тоже не брал.

Comment: Это современная стилистика)) Мне нравится.

Comment: Короче я бы не опирался на кто-нибудь, как на обращение, так как это обращение ни к кому.

Comment: Считайте, что это сленг. И дайте же ответ. Интересно! А потом уж я или еще кто-нибудь))  И какая там растерянность! Говорящий чувствует себя очень уверенно)

Comment: Кто-нибудь, бросьте ваши ручки, и помогите мне. = помогите мне кто-то. Должно быть отрицание, в такой просьбе.

Comment: Смысл да, такой (вы уже предлагаете свои сленговые варианты!).  Но форма интересная. надо дать ей характеристику. И этот стиль свободный, он никому "не должен".

Comment: Не знаю, чем они сленговые.

Comment: О, кто-нибудь, приди, нарушь
Чужих людей соединенность... /// Это современная стилистика с большой бородой.

Comment: Новое — это хорошо забытое старое. Ничто не ново под луною...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Можете, **кто-нибудь**, взять-таки чёрно-гелевую ручку, т. к., очевидно, у меня её нет-с.*

Непосредственные участники речевого общения лучше понимают **смысл** сказанного, чем сторонние наблюдатели. Но можно представить следующий вариант: *Здесь нужна черная гелевая ручка. У кого-нибудь есть? У меня, конечно же, нет.*

Но в данном случае конкретная семантика не так важна, основное внимание нужно уделить **грамматическому** анализу.

1. Рассмотрим предложение:  *Может кто-нибудь взять ручку…*  Очевидно, что здесь подходит только форма ед. числа (***может***), но не мн. числа (***можете***). Поэтому местоимение **кто-нибудь** однозначно нужно обособить.
2. Можно ли считать "кто-нибудь" **обращением**? В общем-то да, это функция именно обращения.

**КТО-НИБУДЬ**, местоим. сущ. Какой-л. человек, безразлично кто. Позовите кого-нибудь сюда! Хочется о ком-нибудь заботиться.

Но стоит вспомнить о том, что, к примеру, **личное местоимение**  не так часто бывает обращением. В правилах **[Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=129#pp129)** указаны все варианты, когда это возможно (нужна частица или определительный оборот).  Однако у **[Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126#pp126)** такой вариант допускается: Ступай за шестым — ты! (Т.) "Тише, вы!" — крикнула Феня.

**И вывод:** да, это обращение.

Comment: Но произношение разное: *Можете(,) кто-нибудь(,) взять-таки чёрно-гелевую ручку. Можете, Шарон, взять-таки чёрно-гелевую ручку.*

Comment: Ну и смыл: *Может кто-нибудь всё-таки взять чёрно-гелевую ручку* — что здесь делает "всё-таки"?

Comment: Может кто-нибудь наконец-таки взять чёрно-гелевую ручку...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, мне кажется, что "кто-нибудь" употребляется в связке утверждением через негативную посылку, либо в предложениях утверждениях имеющих яркую эмоциональную окраску.

> — Разве в этом кто-нибудь сомневается? — тихо сказала бабушка.

То есть "**нет**, все уверены".

> — И если счас кто-нибудь заявит, что пахнет клопами, — дам бутылкой по голове.

**Не говорите**, что пахнет клопами.

> — Тань, ты не знаешь: у вас кто-нибудь менялся?

Я **не знаю**, менялся ли кто-то, а ты - знаешь?

Ну и тд.

Теперь посмотрим, что написал-с Леопольд лапкой:

> Можете(,) кто-нибудь(,) взять-таки чёрно-гелевую ручку, т. к.,
> очевидно, у меня её нет-с.

Ага, есть добавка, что ручки таки нет, но правда ли это или шутка?

То есть подобное предложение должно звучать так:

> Можете кто-нибудь не брать чёрную гелевую ручку, так как я принесу две.

или так

> Можете, кто-нибудь, дайте гелевую ручку! Помогите!

Либо нужно употребить вместо кто-нибудь кто-то:

> Можете кто-то принести ручку, так как я забыл?