# Можете(,) кто-нибуть(,) мне сказать

Tags: запятые

Совы, а нельзя по пункту после 11-го – http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126 –Розенталя оправдать то, почему здесь не нужна запятая? Или она всё-таки нужна?

`Помогите(,) кто-нибудь(,) мне.`

`Можете(,) кто-нибуть(,) мне сказать, как там Леопольдчик?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятые таки нужны:

***Помогите, кто-нибудь, мне***;

***Можете, кто-нибудь, мне сказать, как там Леопольдчик?***

Слово ***кто-нибудь*** в таких случаях является обращением.

См. [вопрос об обособлении](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475262/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C). Кстати, этот вопрос вы и задавали. Принятый вами ответ учатника Sharon подходит и к этой ситуации.